# How can I get a right query result in MongoDB (specially nested array)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I guessed when I run that MongoDB Query then I can get only filtered port_code 'http_https' data but it wasn't. All data is selected.
How can I fix my Query? Would you give me some guides?

**Query**

```
{'port_info': {'$elemMatch': {'port_code': 'http_https'}}}
```

**Documents**

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6267a966fe9fa7f41d42d255"
  },
  "new_yn": "Y",
  "port_info": [
    {
      "ip_port": "199.20.93.164:80",
      "use_yn": "Y",
      "comment": "",
      "port_code": "http_https",
      "uri_info": [
        {
          "uri": "199.20.93.164/",
          "status_code": 404
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ip_port": "199.20.93.164:5985",
      "use_yn": "Y",
      "comment": "",
      "port_code": "http_https",
      "uri_info": [
        {
          "uri": "199.20.93.164:5985",
          "status_code": 200
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ip_port": "199.20.93.164:21 ",
      "use_yn": "Y",
      "comment": "",
      "port_code": "ftp"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      port_info: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$port_info",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item.port_code", "http_https"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/36aJ36QLH_K)

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I make those queries? I thought that project just for using get fields.

Comment: I don't understand the question "How can I make those queries?" Can you clarify? `$project` is a way to format your documents. `$filter` is a way to format them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I mean.. I'm struggling to make query in MongoDB. That's why wrote that sentence.